# accept function waits while packet has been sent

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, go, camera

There's a source (camera) which sends notifications (motion alarms) to port 8085 of a server I've subscribed its IP for it. Maybe in such a negotiation I can't call it 'server', but it's our server which serves some other things.
I've written two programs for receiving and echoing current motion status, for now only on screen. Packets which are received are in shape of XML which I may parse and find the required info. For testing, I just extract times which are labeled UtcTime. Another machine subscribed itself to the same camera by using Onvif Device Manager, so that I may check whether I miss some 'times'. One of these programs are in GoLang and one is in C++. The former one works as expected while the latter one doesn't. Maybe this one (C++) has been my first experience in socket programming. I didn't use any additional library while in C++ and I used the traditional socket programming method not to be required to use any additional library at customer site too. The problem is that ODM echos new times (or say notification messages) as well as the GoLang code while the C++ code sticks at accept function (accepting... message). I give you both for investigation.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func count() (f func() int) {
    var counter int
    f = func() int {
        counter++
        return counter
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", Server)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8085", nil)
}

func Server(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    str := string(body)
    for {
        index := strings.Index(str, "UtcTime")
        if index == -1 {
            break
        }
        part := str[index+20 : index+28]
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", part)
        str = str[index+28:]
    }
}
```

This was the code in GoLang which works properly. Now the C++ code which doesn't work as expected and sticks on accept:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>

#define DBG printf("%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define DIE die(__FILE__, __LINE__)

void die(const char *file, int line)
{
    printf("%s:%d: %s\n", file, line, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

std::string extractTime(const char *utc)
{
    char buf[80];
    memcpy(buf, utc + 11, 8);
    buf[9] = 0;
    return buf;
}

int main()
{
    printf("creating socket...\n");
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == -1)
        DIE;
    int reuseaddr = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(reuseaddr)) == -1)
        DIE;

    printf("binding...\n");
    sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8085);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
        DIE;

    printf("listening...\n");
    if (listen(sock, SOMAXCONN) == -1)
        DIE;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(addr);
    while (true)
    {
        printf("accepting...\n");
        int new_sock = accept(sock, 0, 0);
        if (new_sock < 0)
            DIE;
        const int buf_size = 80;
        char buf[buf_size * 2 + 1];
        memset(buf, 0, buf_size);
        int read_size;
        std::string time;
        while (true)
        {
            memcpy(buf, buf + buf_size, buf_size);
            read_size = recv(new_sock, buf + buf_size, buf_size, 0);
            if (read_size < 0)
                DIE;
            buf[buf_size + read_size] = 0;
            char *p = strstr(buf, "UtcTime");
            if (p && (p - buf < buf_size))
            {
                char buf2[80];
                char *p2 = strstr(p + 9, "\"");
                if (p2)
                {
                    memcpy(buf2, p + 9, p2 - p - 9);
                    buf2[p2 - p - 9] = 0;
                    time = extractTime(buf2);
                    printf("%s\n", time.c_str());
                }
            }
            if (strstr(buf, "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"))
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

1. accept function sticks and I terminate the program by Ctrl+C. The next time I run the program (C++) I get the packets I couldn't get before!
2. OS is Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). The GoLang code works in the same OS.

Update:
The C++ code now uses a separate process for receiving packets:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string>

#define DBG printf("%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define DIE die(__FILE__, __LINE__)

void die(const char *file, int line)
{
    printf("%s:%d: %s\n", file, line, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}

std::string extractTime(const char *utc)
{
    char buf[80];
    memcpy(buf, utc + 11, 8);
    buf[9] = 0;
    return buf;
}

void receive(int s2)
{
    const int buf_size = 80;
    char buf[buf_size * 2 + 1];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    int read_size;
    std::string time;
    FILE *fp = fopen("dump.bin", "ab");
    if (!fp)
        DIE;
    while (true)
    {
        memcpy(buf, buf + buf_size, buf_size);
        read_size = recv(s2, buf + buf_size, buf_size, 0);
        if (read_size < 0)
            DIE;
        if (read_size == 0)
            break;
        if (fwrite(buf + buf_size, buf_size, 1, fp) != 1)
            DIE;
        buf[buf_size + read_size] = 0;
        //printf("%d bytes received: '%s'\n", read_size, buf + buf_size);
        char *p = strstr(buf, "UtcTime");
        if (p && (p - buf < buf_size))
        {
            char buf2[80];
            char *p2 = strstr(p + 9, "\"");
            if (p2)
            {
                memcpy(buf2, p + 9, p2 - p - 9);
                buf2[p2 - p - 9] = 0;
                time = extractTime(buf2);
                printf("%s\n", time.c_str());
            }
        }
        if (read_size < buf_size)
            break;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    close(s2);
}

int main()
{
    printf("creating socket...\n");
    int s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s1 == -1)
        DIE;
    int reuseaddr = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s1, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &reuseaddr, sizeof(reuseaddr)) == -1)
        DIE;

    printf("binding...\n");
    sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8085);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    if (bind(s1, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1)
        DIE;

    printf("listening...\n");
    if (listen(s1, 0) == -1)
        DIE;
    socklen_t size = sizeof(addr);
    while (true)
    {
        printf("accepting...\n");
        int s2 = accept(s1, 0, 0);
        if (s2 < 0)
            DIE;
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            receive(s2);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Update:
I examined C# too:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace tcplistener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int port = 8081;

            TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Socket socketConnection = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                var buf = new byte[80000];
                var size = socketConnection.Receive(buf);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes received", size);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, size).Substring(0, 80));
                socketConnection.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anthough this code also doesn't work as expected, I could find some clues. You see that I changed the port to 8081. This is because 8085 had got full! This is what I conclude and you should confirm whether I'm right. First time, when I ran the program I got the following output:

```
2919 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
5395 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
7871 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
13408 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
16503 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
18979 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
21455 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
23931 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
26407 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
28883 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
31359 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33835 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
43739 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
45260 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
36500 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
45260 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
42340 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
33580 bytes received
POST /behnama-subscription HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.14.127:8081
SOAPAction: http
```

Wonderful! It seems that Receive doesn't read out (doesn't move away) what it gets. The received packet remains there for the next time I call Receive again. The third time the newly received packet is read as well as the two old ones! Buffer size grows gradually until it gets large enough. After this, the size remains high, while it may reduce each time or grow! Until I won't get any new packet anymore. Accept doesn't return and the port gets full and useless. If I run the program again, I get no answer anymore and it sticks at AcceptSocket OR the whole buffer is accepted at once and the second call to AcceptSocket sticks.
So in glance, I may say that the problem seems to be caused by the received packet not being freed by recv. I think the same happens for a C++ program. But what about the GoLang code? I think it may work because size of buffer is not limited as it is in C++ or C# codes. Maybe if I leave it running, the system memory gets full. Size of buffer may be the barrier. Anyway, assuming my assumptions to be correct, what can I do you think? What's the problem in my code that doesn't cause the buffer to get free? And what can I do?

Comment: Use `strace` to verify that your alleged claim is true and this blocks inside `accept()`. The shown code may not be actually doing what you think it's doing. The shown C++ code is flawed and results in undefined behavior due to accessing uninitialized memory. The logic for handling the input buffer is broken and it will attempt to parse uninitialized memory. The purpose of all these buffer machinations is somewhat unclear, and doesn't appear to serve any useful purpose.

Comment: use this example [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/][]

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I don't know strace, but when I put printf after accept and it doesn't print anything, this means that it's stuck in accept, doesn't it? And about the uninitialized buffer, you're right and I updated the code. But certainly it doesn't change the behavior of the code. The logic for handling the input buffer is not to parse a broken string which is not fully available. It's clear and it's a good mechanism for this purpose.

Comment: @yaodav: The link seems to be broken. It says "Nothing Here!"

Comment: @hamidi https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-cc-handling-multiple-clients-on-server-without-multi-threading/   try now

Comment: @yaodav: thanks. I will investigate.

Comment: why isn't your go server sending anything ? why aren't you writing to `w http.ResponseWriter` ? Btw, what is the format of the message? Let's not reverse engineer it from your code

Comment: @UmNyobe: The camera is not expecting to receive anything from my side. It's just a notification message which it sends when it detects a motion. The format is XML, I told.

Comment: @yaodav: I think the server in this model is my side and the client is camera. Although I'm not going to implement a service for the camera, the initiation of data to be sent is from the camera. So, I just have only ONE client. The link you provided is talking about handling multiple clients. Is it still applicable, you think?

Comment: @hamidi fisrt of all you can use it only for one client also, second this is link for one client https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/

Comment: @yaodav: I think you suggest that a second notification message is lost because the processing of the first one takes time. But as I said, I put the whole processing of the notification messages (if recv is a time consuming task) in a separate process and this didn't solve the problem. Besides, the next time is run the program I get the second message!

Comment: @yaodav: thanks for the second link too. As you see I did the process step by step as the image and it doesn't use any select.

Comment: @yaodav: I built the code and ran it for test after changing the port to 8085. I wonder why random ports are connected! I also wonder how the program terminates while there's an endless loop.

Comment: @yaodav: Abnormal program termination was because of send! When i commented the two send calls, it didn't happen. Besides, this code doesn't work too. Something should be done in this special case which we don't. But what is it? Maybe we should really send something to camera (like a packet to indicate we've received its packet and are ready to get the next one)?

Comment: In contrast the Go code works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ variant has some interesting flaws:

- You initialize the first 80 (`buf_size`) characters of `buf`, but then read from the uninitialized next 80 (the first `memcpy`).
- You `memcpy` 80 bytes from the second half of the buffer into the first, regardless of how many useful/initialized bytes are actually *in* the buffer (either half).
- You call `accept` once, to get a connected socket, then read until error and exit.  This destroys the listening socket with the remaining connections un-accepted.  If you get EOF (`read_size` is 0), you spin (probably) forever without exiting, since every future `read` will also return 0.
- If you find the string `"UtcTime"` anywhere in the buffer, you search for a double quote that occurs starting 9 bytes later, even if `"UtcTime"` is less than 9 bytes away from the end of the buffer.

I suspect that if you fix all of these, things may work rather better.  In general, a server should spin off a thread or process to handle each new incoming connection and have the main thread/process go back to `accept` to wait for additional sockets.  (This is all a lot easier to code in Go, which has all the right stuff for doing this built in.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. 1. You were right about reading uninitialized buffer. I initialized the first part and used memcpy to copy the uninitialized part over it. I changed the code to initialize the whole buffer. 2. It seems to be a dumb copy, but it doesn't cause any problem. The second part includes the read buffer terminating with \0. So, strstr works properly, even if additional characters from previous read be copied as well. 3. I changed the code to call recv in a separate process, but it didn't change the behavior. Because the problem is not caused by the delay in calling the next accept

Comment: Besides, I changed the code to check read_size and if it's equal to zero, it leaves the loop. 4. The camera sends UtcTime every time if format of UtcTime="..., so why I should not count on it? The quotation mark is always 8 characters after U.
I update the question to include these changes.

Comment: You could receive less than the entire packet. The Go routine you're using (`io.ReadAll`) reads the entire input into a buffer, rather than trying to use a sliding window; that's probably a better strategy.

Comment: 1. recv is called until the whole buffer is read. This should lead to the same result. 2. I used that strategy too. A large enough buffer (80K) was used with the same result. Something else in this code is not working properly which seems to be hidden out of our sights.

Comment: It's worth breaking this down into something more testable, perhaps. Have the parent do the listen-and-accept; fork (as you do now) and have the child read to EOF and just save the data to a plain file, and then exit (a small bug in the updated code: you should exit so that the child doesn't try to accept() - though that should actually work anyway). Then, try just the "extract the time" code against the plain file, instead of against something looping with listen-and-accept calls.

Comment: Let me see whether I could figure out your way. Just read one packet at a time and exit and then process the file instead of the received packet on the fly, right? But, what differ? I should write a listener daemon anyway. You say that the child process may accept. How? It just call recv. Regardless of what it does with s2, the main process goes to listen again on s1 to accept the next packet.

Comment: Your current code reads (very simplified): `forever { s2 = accept(); if (fork() == 0) use(s2); }` So if fork returns 0, we're in the child: we call use(s2) and go around the loop again, to accept. If fork returns > 0, we're in the parent: we don't call use(s2) and go around the loop again, to accept. So now you have two accept-ing processes.

Comment: I'm suggesting: `forever { s2 = accept(); if (fork() == 0) { use(s2); _exit(0); } }` and making `use()` debuggable by having it loop with `n = read(fd, buf, size); if (n==0) { close(stream); return}; fwrite(stream, buf, n, 1); }` with `stream` referring to a unique temp file. So now all the output is in unique temp files, and you can use a separate program that has no socket() calls to verify that open/read/extract works.

Comment: Once the logic of the two separate programs—one that acts as a server and dumps to temp files, and one that reads temp files that you can inspect with hexdump and/or your editor—is all working, you can re-combine it into one C++ program.

Comment: Good note about accept being called by the child process. I update the code to correct this issue. But, the problem simplified! Once I didn't get even one packet. This means that the first accept could not be passed by (didn't return), so that the remainder of the work is not important, whether forked, whether processed in the main thread, anything else. So, something is wrong somewhere else, maybe before calling accept!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205725/discussion-between-hamidi-and-torek).

Comment: Did you get the chat session? I've something there for you.

Comment: No, I went to bed. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh I see :) No you should not be sorry about it. During this time, I got some new conclusions and I updated the question to share them with you. Buffer gets full and new packets can't be received anymore.

Comment: The changing port is quite odd, but the rest of this suggests that your camera uses something along the lines of websockets, not a simple tcp-session-per-image, and requires acknowledgement or it re-sends. Your Go program implements a full web-server, so your C++ or C# program will need to as well.

Comment: good answer. first, I say that the notification message I get from camera have nothing to do with images. They include no image data. They're just notification messages. Let's consider this scenario: Since the camera doesn't get any acknowledge from me, it assumes that I've not got the message it had sent. So with the second accept it includes the previous message too.

Comment: Now Content-Length grows gradually (only grows) and the message repeats each time. So the question is: How can I tell the camera that I've received what you sent! Don't send it again!

Comment: I can't continue this session, I have other things I need to do. Read up on web servers if you plan to write one.

Comment: It doesn't relate to web server itself. The camera is using Pausable Subscription Management standard notification mechanism from OASIS. In their documents I couldn't find the format of this acknowledgement. It's the key in solving this problem.